# Variable URL parameter triggers 403 forbidden error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a strange problem with my function.

My javascript code is:

```
function makeGIF(x) {
gifshot.createGIF({
    images: [
       x
    ]
}, function (obj) {
    if (!obj.error) {
        var image = obj.image, animatedImage = document.createElement('img');
        animatedImage.src = image;
        document.body.appendChild(animatedImage);
    }
});
}

$('div[class="waka"]').each(function(index,item){
    var urls = $(item).text();
    makeGIF(urls)
});
```

**html code contains multiple waka divs:**

```
<div class="waka" style="display:none">'http://localhost/media/2015/05/8fff824ba3731fac7171b6eb3996d2cf-250x334.jpg','http://localhost/media/2015/05/50dbd1588296572ffcf7d120a85dc4f1-250x334.jpg','http://localhost/media/2015/05/ddf02babac0535b310ef531f773c754d-250x334.jpg',</div>
```

And in console log I'm getting 403 forbidden errors for URLS. Upon just copy pasting the plain URLs in function, everything works fine. Please check the screenshot.

**[Screenshot of errors](http://i.imgur.com/Bz0IjxW.jpg)**

Comment: Did you notice you have a comma at the end of the url list in the div?

Comment: Obviously `gifshot.createGIF` creates wrong `.src` content, because `http://localhost/'http://whatever','http://whatelse'` is clearly a wrong URL for one single image

Comment: That comma does nothing. I tried removing that too.

Comment: Are you sure that a command separated list of URLs in single quote is exactly what `gifshot.createGIF` expects? It doesn't seem so

Comment: @devnull69 Exactly. For that I tried a silly method. I removed the first occurrence of http://localhost/ with nothing from string. But that didn't work either :D

Comment: `'url', 'url', 'url'` is the right format for `gifshot.createGIF`

Comment: Nope, `gifshot.createGIF` expects an array of URL strings. The result of `images: [x]` is an array with one single element, a single string that contains all the URLs. Try this `makeGIF(urls.replace(/'/g, '').split(','))` and then `images: x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

you have a string not an array out of your div's text:

```
<div class="waka" style="display:none">
   'http://localhost/media/2015/05/8fff824ba3731fac7171b6eb3996d2cf-250x334.jpg',
   'http://localhost/media/2015/05/50dbd1588296572ffcf7d120a85dc4f1-250x334.jpg',
   'http://localhost/media/2015/05/ddf02babac0535b310ef531f773c754d-250x334.jpg',
</div>
```

So this in line:

```
var urls = $(item).text();
```

The `var urls` is not an array. If you try doing `typeOf(urls)` you can find this is a `String` not an `Object`.

---

Before any execution of js better to serve the urls comma separated but without any quotes:

```
<div class="waka" style="display:none">
   http://localhost/media/2015/05/8fff824ba3731fac7171b6eb3996d2cf-250x334.jpg,
   http://localhost/media/2015/05/50dbd1588296572ffcf7d120a85dc4f1-250x334.jpg,
   http://localhost/media/2015/05/ddf02babac0535b310ef531f773c754d-250x334.jpg
</div>
```

So, my solution is to use `split()` method to create array out of string.

```
function makeGIF(x) {
   gifshot.createGIF({
      images: x // now x here is an array
   }, function (obj) {
      if (!obj.error) {
          var image = obj.image, animatedImage = document.createElement('img');
          animatedImage.src = image;
          document.body.appendChild(animatedImage);
      }
   });
}

$('.waka').each(function(index,item){ // and change the selector.
    var urls = $(item).text().split(',');
    makeGIF(urls)
});
```

Comment: The resulting strings inside the array will contain extra single quotes that should be removed either from HTML or from the single strings in the splitted array

Comment: @devnull69 absolutely this can be done. either way. But better serve there without quotes and comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="waka" style="display:none">http://localhost/media/2015/05/8fff824ba3731fac7171b6eb3996d2cf-250x334.jpg,http://localhost/media/2015/05/50dbd1588296572ffcf7d120a85dc4f1-250x334.jpg,http://localhost/media/2015/05/ddf02babac0535b310ef531f773c754d-250x334.jpg</div>
```

and then

```
function makeGIF(x) {
gifshot.createGIF({
    images: 
       x
    }, function (obj) {
    if (!obj.error) {
        var image = obj.image, animatedImage = document.createElement('img');
        animatedImage.src = image;
        document.body.appendChild(animatedImage);
    }
});
}

$('div[class="waka"]').each(function(index,item){
    var urls = $(item).text();
    makeGIF(urls.split(','));
});
```

If you don't want (or cannot) remove the single quotes from HTML, you can do this

```
function makeGIF(x) {
gifshot.createGIF({
    images: 
       x
    }, function (obj) {
    if (!obj.error) {
        var image = obj.image, animatedImage = document.createElement('img');
        animatedImage.src = image;
        document.body.appendChild(animatedImage);
    }
});
}

$('div[class="waka"]').each(function(index,item){
    var urls = $(item).text();
    makeGIF(urls.replace(/'/g, '').split(','));
});
```